# How to use redux to save data onSubmit Handler | React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

how can I use redux so that my values of my form get accesible to other components.Currently I've this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AdminConfig extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state=({
      payerName:'',
      payerAddress:''
    })

    this.onPayerNameChange = this.onPayerNameChange.bind(this);
    this.onPayerAddressChange = this.onPayerAddressChange.bind(this);
    this.onAdminFormSubmit = this.onAdminFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onPayerNameChange(e){
    this.setState({
      payerName: e.target.value
    })
  }
  onPayerAddressChange(e){
    this.setState({
      payerAddress: e.target.value
    })
  }
  onAdminFormSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    // I guess here goes the magic

  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="container ">
        <form className="admin-form" onSubmit={this.onAdminFormSubmit}>

          <div className="row">
            <div className="jumbotron col-md-12">
              <h4>PAYER INFORMATION</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <div className="panel panel-primary">
                <div className="panel-heading">Payer Name</div>
                <div className="panel-body">
                  <input
                    onChange={this.onPayerNameChange}
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="payerName"
                    placeholder="Payer Name" />
                  <div className="panel-body" id="getResult"><p>Payer Name: {this.state.payerName}</p></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <div className="panel panel-primary">
                <div className="panel-heading">Payer Address</div>
                <div className="panel-body">
                  <input
                    onChange={this.onPayerAddressChange}
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="payerAddress"
                    placeholder="Payer Address" />
                  <div className="panel-body" id="getResult"><p>Payer Address: {this.state.payerAddress}</p></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Apply config</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default AdminConfig
```

Im using a boilerplate called redux simple starter from Stephen Grider and there is a directory for actions and reducers. Whats next in order to apply redux to my form ?

Comment: Assuming you have redux already setup, you will need to connect this component using react-redux. Then you'll need to create an action that you will dispatch in your "onAdminFormSubmit" function. Lastly, you'll need to create a reducer that keys off your action to actually insert the data into your store state.

Comment: Thats actually what I want to do, but i dont know how

Comment: What you're asking to do is pretty standard Redux. I suggest you spend some time going through the Redux docs. It tells you exactly how to create an action/reducer, how to connect your component, and dispatch your action. http://redux.js.org/